# System Monitoring Utility for PTI-GPU tool Sysmon (Only for Intel internal display)

Tags: 22.04, intel-graphics, gpu, ubuntu-one-api

**Overview:**
I use the tool which can profilling tools interfaces for GPU (PTI for GPU) and Linux "top" like utility to monitor GPUs installed on a system;.
And I try to get per process utilization of memory by Intel tool "sysmon".
But I got a problem that I can't shown in process's information. As the following picture.
***I have no idea to show process utilization of memory. How can I do?***

sysmon process shown unknown:

[image: Screenshot 1]

**System Information:**

1. Ubuntu 22.04
2. CPU-i5-12600HE
3. GPU-Intel(R) UHD Graphics 730
4. Linux kernel 5.19.0-41

**Sysmon Prerequisites**
As the following, then I have already installed those package.

- Cmake
- Git
- Python
- oneAPI Level Zero Loader
- Intel(R) Graphics Compute Runtime for oneAPI Level Zero and OpenCL(TM) Driver
- Intel(R) Metrics Discovery Application Programming Interface
- Metrics Library for Metrics Discovery API (Metrics Library for MD API)
- Intel(R) oneAPI Base Toolkit
- libdrm

**Short step:**
1.`$ source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh`

[image: Screnshot 2]

2.`$ cd <pti-gpu>/tools/sysmon/build`
3.`$ ./sysmon -p`

**Complementary:**
This picture is normal execution sample from network download.
***And I think that does the oneAPI only support Intel Iris graphic?***
sysmon normal sample:

[image: Screenshot 3]

If you any suggestion for this, please help.
Thanks a lot.